# Javascript :- ExtJS el.dom.innerHtml Removed <link> and <style> tags on IE only It works fine Firefox. when el.dom.innerHtml assign html string

Tags: javascript, extjs

For FireFox el.dom.innerHTML

```
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css">
```

Test

For IE el.dom.innerHTML

Test

In FF the returned el.dom.innerhtml includes the  and  tag but in IE it does not. Are these filtered out by Ext in anyway and if so why?

Below this forum link give solution to override the Ext.element.Update method.

```
Ext.override(Ext.Element, {
    update : function(html, loadScripts, callback){
}
```

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?30110-internet-explorer-autoLoad-css-not-applied

But I have question where I add this function which ExtJs files. because ext-all-2.2.js and ext-base-2.2 is core files of ExtJs Libarary. I put this code in ExtExtension-2.2.js file but Override Update method doesn't fire when assign 
`this.el.dom.innerHtml=Markup` (markup is string which contain html string.)

Please help me which ExtJs file I put function . Ext.Override(Ext.Element) Update Method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That override simply needs to run sometime after the Ext scripts are loaded.  So include a javascript file after including the Ext files, and the method will be overridden.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/ext-all-2.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/myscript.js"></script>
```

The in myscript.js:

```
Ext.override(Ext.Element, {
    update : function(html, loadScripts, callback){
        ...
    }
}
```

Remember though, that Ext isn't magic.  It can't automatically fire the `update` function when simply assigning innerHTML, as that is handled entirely by the browser.  Rather, use the `update` function directly, and that will update the innerHTML:

Instead of:

```
this.el.dom.innerHtml=Markup;
```

use:

```
this.el.update(Markup);
```